# Source control keeps sidebar opening automatically

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am fairly new to VS Code. I really like it, but there is one thing that is extremely annoying and if I cant fix it, I might switch back to vim.

Every time I click into a editor tab (In my case I use a split layout and click into the other split) the source control side bar opens itself. It is really annoying, because it almost takes a quarter of my screen.

How can I disable it fully and only open the bar when I need it?

EDIT 1:
The moment I posted this yesterday it stopped happening. Now it happens again. I have no idea why.

It might be related to the split layout. I just closed the split and reopened it and it stopped happening.

Comment: I might have figured it out. Is it setting `scm providers: Visible` to `0` ?

Comment: Are you sure it is the scm view that is opening and not the file explorer.  File explorer as this functionality by default.  Try setting `explorer.autoReveal` to false.  Otherwise, I don't think the scm view should be doing that.

Comment: it the scm. Even the explorer is closed if I have it open.
Ignore my first comment, please. It happened again. But it is somehow unpredictable when it happens.